# No main method found on extension

Tags: java, program-entry-point

i'm trying to compile this class from a Engine inside of my main program!

I'm trying to make a program that you can extent with extensions

```
Error on: C:\Users\Howl3r\Desktop\New folder\extensions\testExt\TestLoader.java.error.log
Line: -1 - Column: -1

no main method in extensions.testExt.TestLoader
```

Here is the code i'm trying to run with a engine:

```
package extensions.testExt;

import com.l2jsaver.controllers.ExtensionController;

import extensions.testExt.test.Test;

public class TestLoader 
{
    protected static int ID = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ExtensionController.getInstance().getExtensions().put(ID, new Test());
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to run the program? In an IDE or from the command line?

Comment: I'm using eclipse and ant build, i use cmd to run the main jar

Comment: On eclipse if i just run the TestLoader (commented all the imports and work and added a hello world print) it runs! So i believe it has something to do with classpaths but can't figure where the problem is...

Comment: Which version of java do you compile it for? Which on is used on your machine on default?

Comment: I use JDK 1.7.0_75 should i post my ScriptEngine? maybe it messes something up

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with that code, as it exists in isolation. It may be worthwhile to rebuild your eclipse project from scratch, and copy your code files into the new project, just to get your settings back to a sane place.